# Why are functions more efficient the more they are run?

Tags: java, performance, timer

I was testing how long on average this function took to run

```
int prevTime = System.nanoSeconds();
for(int i = 0; i < amountOfTimes; i++;){
    int max = 63;
    value = r.nextInt(101) + 1;
    while(max < value) max >>= 1;
}
totalTime = System.nanoSeconds() - prevTime;
avgTime =  totalTime/amountOfTimes;
```

I have found that the greater amountOfTimes is, the lower avgTime is. I would have expected avgTime to be more or less consistent regardless of the number of times I run the function. When run 1000 times, avgTime is around 222 nanoSeconds, but when run 10^9 times, avgTime is around 16 nanoSeconds.

Why does this get so much more efficient the more it is run?

Comment: [Understanding Java JIT Compilation with JITWatch, Part 1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-evans-pt1-2266278.html)

Comment: [Just-in-time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That's a really interesting thing I didn't realize about Java's JIT. So it varies the extent to which it applies optimizations based on, say, the size of the loop (`amountOfTimes`) in the above example? Also what if `amountOfTimes` is determined by user input rather than a compile-time constant? That blur between runtime input and compile-time value is really interesting to me with the optimization potential of JITs.

Comment: @TeamUpvote When the JIT performs loop unrolling it can get most of the benefit after just a few copies so the actual amount could vary without changing the performance too much.

Comment: I suggest you run it with `-XX:+PrintCompilation` and you will see this method getting optimised and re-optimised to make it faster.

Comment: @TeamUpvote JIT is one of the main reasons why OP's code is the naive way to benchmark a method. It's better to use a framework like JMH for micro benchmark.